# Why do reinforcement algorithms like DQN achieve high performance in game playing

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, reinforcement-learning

Vanilla deep Q learning algorithm is only capable of addressing problem under a **discrete** time scene.

However, it somewhat doesn't make sense to me since I assume the game ( Atari for example) is a **continuous** decision making process.

How could such an algorithm outperform others under an inappropriate scene？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atari is probably a bad example here, since it is actually a discrete game running at some constant framerate. Of course there are many other control problems such as "inverted pendulum" which can be formulated as a continuous time environment.

Also note that the performance of Q-learning quickly degrades as the delta between time-steps decreases (and the environment approaches a continuous version), since at the limit $Q(s,a) = V(s)$, subject to some conditions -- see ["Making Deep Q-learning approaches robust to time discretization"](https://icml.cc/media/Slides/icml/2019/hallb(11-11-00)-11-11-20-4577-making_deep_q-l.pdf)

Comment: So you mean the decrease of alpha, which is the weight put on  future values in the algorithm, lead to the degradation of Q learning algorithm？

Comment: @user9428398: No, he means when the length of each time step $t$ decreases meaningfully e.g. within a physics-based environment where state (and reward signals) evolves strictly according to clock time, not time step id.

Comment: (yes, even if the discount factor is correctly adjusted for shorter time-steps, the difficulty persists)